# Migration Issue with ASP.NET Core 2.2 "cannot be marked as nullable/optional because it has been included in a key"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have the issue after I type the following command with ASP.NET Core 2.2:

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddLoginLogoutTime --context xxxContext
```

and get the following error for the IdentityServer 4

The property 'Id' on entity type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole' cannot be marked as nullable/optional because it has been included in a key {'Id'}.

```
namespace Community.Data.Entities.Users
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        public long? BeforeSpyingOriginalCompanyId { get; set; }

        public bool IsResetPasswordUponLoginNeeded { get; set; }

        public bool IsWelcomingFromTraditionalWebsiteNeeded { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; } = true;

        public bool IsSubscribeWhatsAppMessage { get; set; } = true;

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string VerificationCode { get; set; }

        public DateTime VerificationCodeExpiryDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.ToSqlDefaultDateTime();

        public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        public DateTime LogoutTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Anyone facing this issue and how to solve the error?

Comment: You must give more info about your Identity model configuration.have you modify basic asp.net IdentityUser class model??

Comment: @AminSahranavard you mean the config.cs file?

Comment: Share us information about `IdentityRole` and `xxxContext`, a simple demo to reproduce your issue would be helpful.